# Should I tell an interviewer they hired me for a different job years ago?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

A principal hired me at a school 10 years ago. He was only there for one year. I am now applying for a job at the school he is currently at. Should I mention he hired me years ago in a follow up email? I haven't been asked for an interview yet.

Comment: Obvious question: how did you perform at that job and how did you get on with the principal?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on your resume?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by telling him that? Depending on that is that you should decide to write him, or not, or another completely different possibility.

Comment: I did very well, as I am still there today. It is on my resume, so if he did the math he could figure it out. I was wondering if mentioning it would get me an interview at the new school, or just let him figure it out himself.

Comment: @Prinz  The old job may be on his resume but that doesn't mean that his bosses name is on it.

Comment: @PeterM, That is true, but his old boss, assuming he reads the resume, would recognize that they both worked at the same place at the same time and thus, his boss should remember without the OP having to tell him.

Comment: @Prinz Assuming the the old boss is the same as the new boss and is in the hiring process.  The old boss may not even see the resume this time around

Comment: @PeterM, I see your point - I read the OP's question to be that he was interviewing WITH the old boss.  You are right, if the school has more than one Principal, he may not be interviewing with the same one.

Comment: @Anon - What is your concern with doing this that you felt the need to ask here, rather than just try it and see?

Comment: How much authority does a principal have? Are they the equivalent of a manager or more just another employee? The school-specific hierarchy possibly makes this off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

If someone hired you 10 years ago, the odds are good that they still remember you. The exception would be if you were so ordinary that they basically didn't register you (emotions help memorizing). It's unlikely.

You have zero benefit in bringing the topic up IMHO. If you had a great or terrible performance, rest assured they remember it. If you were neither and they *don't* remember, then at best they play along and wonder wait wtf I actually worked with this person and it was so dull I don't recollect, and at worst they get a stress response because you raised that their memory is oh so fallible and oh crap their boss at the time was just horrendous and it negatively affects you by association.

The best you can do is to build your CV so that it's clearcut you worked with them then. Perhaps also add "looking forward to working you again" if they're the recipient of your cover letter. But leave it at that. Let *them* do the remembering rather than rubbing it in their face.

Comment: The principal at the new school that I would work for is the same one that hired me. He was only there for one year, while the regular principal was on sabbatical. I'm sure it was a crazy year getting to know a whole school of employees and families. So I would not expect him to remember me by name, but he would know the school and year. I do like the idea of "looking forward to working with you again."

Comment: I would assume if it's on your resume you can mention it, especially with a "I remember you, I hope we get along as well as we did the first time!" line. Not that line. That's too open, but you get the idea from Denis' post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that mentioning your old boss is the right approach when talking to an interviewer, especially if you have no idea if you will be working with that old boss.

If you will 100% be working with the old boss and he is in the hiring process then he should be able to do the math himself.

On the other hand if you think you had a good working relationship with your old boss it may be advantageous to contact him directly and tell him that you are applying for a position where he is now.  At the very least this could provide you with valuable inside information about the position and hiring process.

It's not what you know .. it's who you know!

Comment: What if his old boss would give him a good reference?  Current employees, especially management, references have lots of weight many times.

Comment: If you contact him directly, he can also provide a referral which can help you along in the interview process.